# Find all integers $x,y,z$ that satisfied $xy(x^2+y^2)=z^3$

Tags: number-theory

I don't know if I have find all the solution to the problem but I have found 3 of them $(k,0,0)$, $(0,k,0)$, $(4k^3,4k^3,8k^4)$ where $k$ is any integers. The first two solution I just let $z=0$ and then find $x,y$ and the last one I let $x=y$. Please help

Comment: $xy(x^2+y^2)=z^3\implies (2 x y^3 - z^3)^2 + (2 x^2 y^2)^2 = (z^3)^2$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x_0$ and $y_0$, if $ x_0 y_0 (x_0^2 + y_0^2) = a^3 b$ then $x = b^2 x_0, y =  b^2 y_0, z = a b^3$ is a solution.

Comment: It is a lemma or you just solve it? Could you explain where you get them

Comment: The basic point is that the left and right sides are homogeneous of different degree, so scaling appropriately makes them equal.

Comment: I haven't study about homogeneous yet hahah. Where do you recommend me to study about it?

Comment: I mean if you multiply $x$ and $y$ by $t$, you multiply the left side by $t^4$, while if you multiply $z$ by $s$, you multiply the right side by $s^3$.  By adjusting $t$ and $s$ appropriately, you make the two sides equal.